# Find the number of $f: A \to B$ where there is no element in $B$ with $3$ sources

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that $|A| = 8$ and $|B| = 5$. Find the number of functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ such that there is no element in b that has 3 sources (that means, for all $b \in B \rightarrow |\{ a \in A | f(a) = b \} | \neq 3$

This is a question of Graph-Theory from one of my previous exams, but I have absolutely no clue on how to solve it, however, it might have something to do with the ***Erdos-Szekeres*** rule (for all two integers $s$ and $t$ : $R(s,t) \leq {s+t-2 \choose s-1 } $

Answer (score 1):

The total number of functions $A \to B$ is $5^8$.
For each $b \in B$, the number with $|f^{-1}(b)| = 3$ is ${8 \choose 3} 4^5$.
For every $b_1 \ne b_2 \in B$, the number with $|f^{-1}(b_1)| = 3$ and $|f^{-1}(b_2)| = 3$ is ${8 \choose 3} {5 \choose 3} 3^2$.  There are none with 
$|f^{-1}(b)|=3$ for three
 different $b$.  Now use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: This answer is a trivial Enumeration one. (and I have thought of it).
But, is there a way to solve it using graph-theory? (especially the Erdos-Szekeres rule)